# Typo3 cache not used with globalVar typoscript condition

Tags: caching, typo3, typoscript, typo3-7.6.x

I have a multi language Typo3 (7.6.22) setup which causes some caching problems. If I use the following TypoScript condition, only the first accessed language page gets cachhed.

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 < {$lib.sys_language_uid}]
lib.lang.home_action.value = http://{$lib.url.domain}{$lib.url.basePath}{$lib.language}.html
[global]
```

with `$lib.sys_language_uid` defined this way

```
[globalVar = GP:L > 0]
lib.sys_language_uid = 1
[global]
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
lib.sys_language_uid = 2
[global]
...
```

I now wondering, what causes this problem and how I could solve this, without putting the condition inside my fluid templates.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem occurs as your conditions are very complicated to evaluate.

Caching in TYPO3 is done for each condition evaluation (true - false).
ATM I can't say whether conditions in the Constants part are enough to make up separate caches. and also unclear if the evaluation with (changing) constants [*] will create separate caches.

let's see what will happen with differnt values for URL parameter L:

**&L=0 (or not set)**
in constant part no condition is true, so `lib.sys_language_uid` does not get set at all.
So in setup we have:

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 < {$lib.sys_language_uid}]
```

and this is literally (`0 < '{$lib.sys_language_uid}'`) as the constant is not defined. So it evaluates to `TRUE`.

**&L=1**
constants:

```
[globalVar = GP:L > 0]
lib.sys_language_uid = 1
[global]
```

this part is true and we have `lib.sys_language_uid` set to `1`.

in setup we now have the condition

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 < 1]
```

which also evaluates to true.

**&L=2**

```
[globalVar = GP:L > 0]
lib.sys_language_uid = 1
[global]
[globalVar = GP:L = 2]
lib.sys_language_uid = 2
[global]
```

both parts are true and we have `lib.sys_language_uid` set to `2`.

in setup we now have the condition

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 < 2]
```

which also evaluates to true.

**&L=3 (or further values)**
constants:

```
[globalVar = GP:L > 0]
lib.sys_language_uid = 1
[global]
```

only the first part is true and we have `lib.sys_language_uid` set to `1`.

in setup we now have the condition

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 < 1]
```

which also evaluates to true.
**This is the same condition as for `&L=1` and this will use the same cache! BOOM!!**

Result:
[*] changing constants is a bad concept!

use the evaluation of the URL-Parameter in the setup part of TS templates instead of crypt it in the constants part.

Answer (score 0):

It is may the naming convention, but usually things with "lib." are defined in the setup section.

```
[globalVar = LIT:0 < {$lib.sys_language_uid}]
```

If it is the case and you defined it there, then it is a problem, because its value stays the same independent from the language. 
The condition "LIT" can handle only constants.

`{$lib.sys_language_uid}` should be a constant.

BTW

If I have such a problem I always try to "print" the value of that TypoScript constant or cObject into the markup, like:

```
page.headerData.123456 = TEXT
page.headerData.123456 { 
    value = {$lib.sys_language_uid}
    wrap = <test>|</test> 
}
```

Comment: It is defined in the constant section and the code as is, works. The only problem is, that the cache don't work for translated pages